# how to copy content of a folder to another specify folder in grunt-copy task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have this snipped in my gruntfile.js:

```
copy: {
    dist: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                    'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    'bower_components/sass-bootstrap/fonts/*.*',
                    'bower_components/components-font-awesome/{,*/}*.*',
                    'bower_components/ckeditor/**/*.*',
                    'resources/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

this copies all the files from the `src:[...]` to the **same folder** in dist/. How can I achieve that some files get copied directly into the folder?

So for example instead of copying from /resources to "dist/resources", I want to copy to "dist/" directly.

EDIT: to make things clear:

I want all contents of "/resources" to be directly in "/dist". So for example if I have **"resources/data/.."**, I want it to be **"dist/data/.."** Basically the internal folder/file structure in resources should be preserved, but the root should now be /dist instead of /resources

Comment: Specify an explicit target folder?

Comment: how would I do that in my current gruntfile?

Comment: According to [these samples](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile), it would simply be `dist/`  You may need a separate gruntjs file for your custom stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flatten: true, and specify two sets of files (one flattened, the other not).

Here:

```
dist: {
    files: [
        // All these are going (as previously) to be copied along with their dir structure
            {
              expand: true,
              dot: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
              dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
              src: [
                  '*.{ico,txt}',
                  '.htaccess',
                  'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                  'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                  'bower_components/sass-bootstrap/fonts/*.*',
                  'bower_components/components-font-awesome/{,*/}*.*',
                  'bower_components/ckeditor/**/*.*',
                  ]
            },
        // These will get flattened
            {
              expand: true,
              dot: true,
              flatten: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
              dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
              src: [
                  'resources/{,*/}*.*'
                  ]
            }

        ]
    }
},
```

You may also perform transformation on the final path of the file by implementing a custom rename function on your file objects.

More about flatten and rename [here](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically).

[UPDATE]

This below is what you describe in your update (change cwd).

```
dist: {
    files: [
        // All these are going (as previously) to be copied along with their dir structure
            {
              expand: true,
              dot: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
              dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
              src: [
                  '*.{ico,txt}',
                  '.htaccess',
                  'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                  'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                  'bower_components/sass-bootstrap/fonts/*.*',
                  'bower_components/components-font-awesome/{,*/}*.*',
                  'bower_components/ckeditor/**/*.*',
                  ]
            },
            {
              expand: true,
              dot: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/resources',
              dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
              src: [
                  '{,*/}*.*'
                  ]
            }

        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: and what if I want to preserve the structure inside resources but put them into /dist ?

Comment: then use cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/resources' and don't use flatten ;)

Comment: if I dont use flatten the files getcopied into the same structure they were before, but I need the content of "/resources" to be in "/dist" directly.